# How can I import Spring Framework into Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring

I am having trouble importing spring framework into eclipse. I have downloaded spring but am unable to import it. Can anyone help or direct me to a web page that can do so?

Comment: Spring framework actually has Eclipse as its base and after downloading it you just open it and it looks like eclipse.

Comment: @ArthurEirich I assume you're talking about STS, not the Spring Framework. They're wildly different things.

Answer (score 0):

You can either follow this tutorial:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_hello_world_example.htm
or use the spring eclipse plugin (you can find it in eclipse under Help/eclipse marketplace and search for it) 
or you can use a tool to manage your dependencies like maven.

Answer (score 0):

It wouldn't be a bad idea to get familiar with a dependency manager like [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html). For use in Eclipse there is a nice plugin [M2Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/). The `pom.xml` file is what you use to specify your dependencies, and then when you build with Maven it resolves everything for you and downloads automatically anything it needs. This is the example `pom.xml` file from the Maven installation instructions:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>Maven Quick Start Archetype</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.8.2</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

The dependency for the core Spring Framework is

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
  <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

And generally you can find the `pom.xml` dependency specifications at the [Maven Repository](http://mvnrepository.com/). Might seem a little overdone for simply getting Spring into Eclipse, but once you have it set up it is then a snap to add more dependencies down the road, all you do is add the appropriate item to the `pom.xml` file.